# How can I attach a controller to rootDocument without directive?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm making a plugin that manually bootstraps my angular app and uses document as the root. Without using the directive ng-controller, how can I simply attach a controller to my root so that it acts like a global controller, per se? I would have something like this in mind:

```
var myCtrl = function($scope) {
    // Typical controller code
};

var app = angular.module('app',[]).
config(['$controlProvider',function($controlProvider)
{
    // Attaches the controller to the rootScope/ document
    $controlProvider.register('myCtrl',['$scope',myCtrl]);
}]);

angular.bootstrap(document,['app']);
```

One thing that might appear in the answer is the mention of $scope.keys = { ... }. Please explain to me what that is, if it is relevant to the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Just curious as to why you would use a `$provider` in this case?
Simply assign `$rootScope` to your controller's `$scope` in the `run` block like this:
[http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.$controller](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24controller)

```
var ctrl = function($scope) {
    $scope.HelloWorld = "Hello World";
};

var app = angular.module('app',[])
.run(['$rootScope', '$controller', function($rootScope, $controller){   
    var myCtrl = $controller(ctrl, {$scope: $rootScope});
}]);

angular.bootstrap(document,['app']);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/10thfloor/Zaeny/1/ <- working fiddle.

Comment: Could you please add html part too just for the clarification? thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can make a global controller and that global controller is not registered in any of the module, so it would have the scope of the root.

```
function mycontroller($scope){
---Your controller code goes here---
}
```

Comment: How would I inject services like $scope? And do I not need to register with angular?

Comment: see injecting $scope or any service like that you not required any app. you just need to use ng-app at any point before using the functionality of the controller.